# Can't run MIPS binary in qemu

Tags: mips, emulation, qemu, firmware

I'm trying to run a MIPS binary on a full system emulation in qemu in order to search for vulnerabilities in a router firmware.
I'm starting up qemu with the following command: `qemu-system-mips -M malta -m 256 -hda hda.img -kernel vmlinux-4.19.0-14-4kc-malta -initrd initrd.img-4.19.0-14-4kc-malta -append "root=/dev/sda1 console=ttyS0 nokaslr" -nographic -netdev user,id=net0 -device e1000-82545em,netdev=net0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:c9:18:27 -net user -redir tcp:2222::22 -net nic`

The machine boots, I do get a network connection and I was able to install gdb,binwalk etc.

My problem comes when I try to run a binary, for example `./busybox`, I get the output `-bash: ./busybox: No such file or directory` .

But when I run `strace busyboox`, I get:

```
execve("/usr/bin/busybox", ["busybox"], 0x7f7ffa70 /* 20 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55aae000
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x77f07000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=24625, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 24625, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x77f00000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/mips-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\2\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\10\0\0\0\1\0\0%\320\0\0\0004"..., 512) = 512
prctl(PR_GET_FP_MODE)                   = 0
_llseek(3, 724, [724], SEEK_SET)        = 0
read(3, "\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\1GNU\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\0", 32) = 32
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=83944, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 153808, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x77eb0000
mprotect(0x77ec3000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x77ed2000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x12000) = 
0x77ed2000
mmap2(0x77ed4000, 6352, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 
0x77ed4000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/mips-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\2\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\10\0\0\0\1\0\1\244d\0\0\0004"..., 512) = 512
prctl(PR_GET_FP_MODE)                   = 0
_llseek(3, 520, [520], SEEK_SET)        = 0
read(3, "\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3GNU\0\30\335\354\235\fM\241r\346\26\317\341R\305\363\23"..., 36) = 
36
_llseek(3, 828, [828], SEEK_SET)        = 0
read(3, "\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\1GNU\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\0", 32) = 32
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1668292, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 1642000, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x77d1f000
mprotect(0x77e98000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x77ea7000, 28672, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x178000) = 
0x77ea7000
mmap2(0x77eae000, 7696, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 
0x77eae000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x77efe000
set_thread_area(0x77f054a0)             = 0
mprotect(0x77ea7000, 16384, PROT_READ)  = 0
mprotect(0x77ed2000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x55728000, 8192, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x77f09000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
munmap(0x77f00000, 24625)               = 0
getuid()                                = 0
ioctl(2, TIOCGWINSZ, 0x7f9faddc)        = 0
dup2(1, 2)                              = 2
write(2, "BusyBox v1.30.1 (Debian 1:1.30.1"..., 35BusyBox v1.30.1 (Debian 1:1.30.1-4)) = 35
write(2, " multi-call binary.\n", 20 multi-call binary.
)   = 20
write(2, "BusyBox is copyrighted by many a"..., 568BusyBox is copyrighted by many authors between 
1998-2015.
Licensed under GPLv2. See source distribution for detailed
copyright notices.

Usage: busybox [function [arguments]...]
or: busybox --list[-full]
or: busybox --show SCRIPT
or: busybox --install [-s] [DIR]
or: function [arguments]...

BusyBox is a multi-call binary that combines many common Unix
utilities into a single executable.  Most people will create a
link to busybox for each function they wish to use and BusyBox
will act like whatever it was invoked as.

Currently defined functions:
) = 568
write(2, "\t", 1    )                       = 1
write(2, "[", 1[)                        = 1
write(2, ", ", 2, )                       = 2
write(2, "[[", 2[[)                       = 2
write(2, ", ", 2, )                       = 2
write(2, "acpid", 5acpid)                    = 5
write(2, ", ", 2, )                       = 2
write(2, "adjtimex", 8adjtimex)                 = 8
write(2, ", ", 2, )                       = 2
write(2, "ar", 2ar)                       = 2
write(2, ", ", 2, )                       = 2
write(2, "arch", 4arch)                     = 4
write(2, ", ", 2, )                       = 2
write(2, "arp", 3arp)                      = 3
...
...
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Looks like strace gives the wanted output, but I can't figure out what's the porblem when executing normally. Thanks for the help

Comment: Is the busybox binary in the current directory :-)

Comment: Right, for an exact comparison you want to be looking at "strace ./busybox" and "./busybox" (or give the full pathname to the binary in both cases).

Comment: @PeterMaydell when running "strace ./busybox" I get `execve("./busybox", ["./busybox"], 0x7fcb1b90 /* 20 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
strace: exec: No such file or directory
+++ exited with 1 +++
`

Comment: Right, that's your problem, then -- you're trying to run a file that doesn't exist. Figure out where you've actually put the binary you want to run, and use the correct path to it.

Comment: @PeterMaydell I'm running it from /bin, I don't think the directory is wrong... And busybox binary is definitely there

Comment: The error messages you report imply otherwise. There appears to be a 'busybox' in /usr/bin, which is what you get if you run 'busybox' or 'strace busybox' with no arguments. There appears to be no 'busybox' in your current working directory, as neither 'strace ./busybox' nor just './busybox' find it. Again, find the actual path to the binary you run and run it exactly with that path. If it works, great. If it doesn't work, then strace it, again with exactly that path.